# Flextable knit well in .docx locally but on shiny app deployed not

Tags: r, shiny, flextable

I have a shiny app that run some statistical tests and export as .docx (word document) with RMarkdown. I found out that the best way to handle tables is with flextable and pander

When I was trying to make flextable work I realized that my RStudio were utilizng an older version from pander and I manually needed to install a new version from pander (and made it work).

So all my tables works fine when testing locally, but when I deploy my app in shinyapps.io my tables in the word document looks like raw code (image below)

[image]

MY GUESS is: probably the versions I'm using in my RStudio locally are newer and handle properly my tables, and the versions on shinyapps.io are older. Could be that?

On the future I'm gonna put my shiny app in a Digital Ocean Droplet, and there I'll install all the newest versions that I need. That would solve my problem?

If you guys agree with me I'm willing to start paying Digital Ocean just to test this, but would like some feedback that this could solve my problems.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, my guess was right!

To know the shinyapps.io pando version I've used pandoc_version() from package rmarkdown, and I got 2.3.1 (older than mine local that is 2.7.3)

So I downgraded my local pandoc version to 2.6 (just to test out a not so old version). This got me the same problem with shinyapps.io (raw xml)

To test out again, I upgraded my local pandoc to 2.7.3 again e tested again. Guess what? All is working fine.

My problem is the pandoc version from shinyapps.io, and this will be handled when I deploy my own Rstudio server (with the newest pandoc version).

Thanks all!

Notice that: to make these tests, I didn't change NOTHING in my RMarkdown file.